# layerslider WP 100% width and height

Tags: html, wordpress, fullscreen

Can someone please guide me how to get an image full screen so that it stays in the centre both horizontal and vertical like the link provided.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php

I'm only after the background bit and i need the image in a div apposed to in the css like in the example as i am using it for a slider in wordpress.

Comment: I googled "full page background image" and this tutorial came up. http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see those other parts, it's got me a bit closer but i'm not quite there, it misses off the top and bottom, see here http://www.digitalkandi.com/test_v3/

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your LayerSlider display at 100% height and width, leave the "Slider height" attribute in "Slider Settings" blank, and then use a script like the following to set the height:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function resize()
    {
        var heights = window.innerHeight;
        document.getElementById("layerslider_1").style.height = heights + "px";
    }
    resize();
    window.onresize = function() {
        resize();
    };
</script>
```

Insert the script into your footer.php file before the closing body tag. If your slider ID isn't number 1, then change "layerslider_1" to the correct ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can add style to the div element

```
<div style="background: url(images/xyz.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;">...</div>
```

I just took the css from your sample page and copy/pasted!

Comment: Thanks for that and i'm sure normally that would work but I tried your code and replaced the url with a shortcode as it's to be used with layerslider and I can't get it to work, here's the code i used     `<div style="background: url(<?php echo do_shortcode('[layerslider id="1"]'); ?>) no-repeat center center fixed;">...</div>`